# Is it advisable to have the ® symbol in an alt attribute?

Tags: html

Is it advisable to have the ® symbol in `<img>`'s tag `alt` attribute or not? I am interested in knowing if there are problems with using the Registered symbol, such as not rendering properly in some browsers.

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: If it won't render properly in any browser

Comment: Sorry if I'm stating the obvious but the `alt` attribute is not expected to render unless the image fails to load.

Comment: I have not encountered any issues, but its critical that the symbol always renders correctly when it should render, otherwise I will be using the text "(R)" instead.

Comment: Why can't you use the symbol?

Comment: I don't know if you can't but using symbols in the title tag are problematic, so I am confirming an alt tag is a safe place for a registered symbol.

Comment: @ktamlyn, yes, this sign is normally rendered by all modern browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your character encoding for the file. If the encoding is set correctly, the browser should display it correctly. There is nothing in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#alt) that suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

By the specifications, an `alt` attribute value may contain any character (though some characters need to be escaped in HTML markup). In practice, old browsers had many limitations in this area, but this is hardly relevant these days.

The main questions are: 1) When the attribute value is rendered as text, will the fonts available contain the character? Most probably. The “®” character is present in all normal fonts. 2) When the attribute value is rendered in speech or Braille, what will happen? I would not be so sure of this. Speech browsers might not know what to do with special characters. And would you really like to have alt="ACME® and Foobar® products" read e.g. as “ACME registered sign and Foobar registered sign products”? What purpose would it serve?

There are also font quality issues. Many fonts contain “®” in a rather small size, whereas a few fonts like Cambria contain a rather large “®”. The font used to render `alt` attributes might be outside the author’s control. (In many browsers, it is affected by CSS, but e.g. IE 9 uses a font determined by system settings.)

The bottom line is: No, it is not advisable, but it is technically possible, with various risks.